# Continuity Argument?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $f(x)$ be a nonnegative, nondecreasing and continuous function defined on $[0,a]$. Assume that if $f(x)\le \sqrt\epsilon$ then $f(x)\le \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\epsilon}$ holds for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. Then how can I prove that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small then $f(x)\le C\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,a]$ with some positive constant $C$?

Comment: Are you sure about the condition? As written, it implies that $f(x)\equiv 0$ or $f(x)\ge C$ for some $C>0$

Comment: I think if $\epsilon is small$ then $C\epsilon<\sqrt\epsilon$ but I cannot go further

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the comment, how about if I add the condition $f(0)\le \epsilon$?

Comment: If $C$ depends on $\epsilon$, then you are just asking how to prove that $f(x)$ is bounded on $[0,a]$. But that is true for all continuous functions. It is trivial to prove in this case because $f(x)$ is non-decreasing, so $f(x)\le f(a)$.

Comment: @almagest I think $C$ does not depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Keverta I agree, it states in Lemma 7.1 that the constant $C$ is independent of $x$ and the inequality holds for all $\epsilon$ in some interval.

Comment: But glancing at the proof of Lemma 7.1, I suspect it depends on properties of their particular $f(x)$. I don't think they are claiming it is true for all $f(x)$.

Comment: Also, they are not claiming that $f(x)<C\epsilon$ for all $x$. They are only claiming that if $f(x)<\sqrt\epsilon$, then $f(x)<C\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the context and application, but for what it's worth
$$ \forall \epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_0]\colon (a\le\sqrt \epsilon\to a\le\tfrac12\sqrt \epsilon)$$
is equivalent to
$$ a\le 0\lor a> \epsilon_0^2$$

Comment: Thanks but would you let me know some details for this?

Comment: I'm wondering that if I can prove $a\le C\epsilon + C'a^2$ if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small for some positive constant $C, C'$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is nondecreasing then $f(a)\geq f(x)$ for any $x\in [0,a]$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be a real number then there exists $C$ such that $f(a) \leq C\epsilon$ hence $f(x) \leq f(a) \leq C\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,a]$ I do not know why you need the condition $f(x) \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$ then $f(x)\leq \frac12 \sqrt{\epsilon}$?